# Multi-threading and logical-channels in smart cards

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

As far as we know, Java Cards doesn't support **multi-threading**. The question is that, how they can have more than one logical channel but don't support multi-threading? And why they need more than one logical channel?

In my case I have a java card that support three logical channel. I installed `Applet-A` and `Applet-B` on my card. then I sent a *SELECT* command for Applet-A via logical channel-1, and right after that I sent another *SELECT* command for Applet-B via channel-2.

In this moment, I can send and APDUs to both Applet-A and Applet-B in a row without any other Select command. Isn't this Multi-Threading? I mean the JCRE must keep both Applet-A and Applet-B selected, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't multi-threading. With multi-threading it is required that multiple *processor threads* run *at the same time*. This means that you have a requirements for multiple stacks as well.

On the other hand, for logical channels it is only required that the applet state is aware of the multiple logical channels. In Java Card, you do have support for logical channels, but you are still required to design and keep a state machine. How the state - such as authentication state - between logical channels is divided is not specified in ISO/IEC 7816-4 where logical channels are defined. The only thing that the runtime is required to do is to remember the selection state of the logical channels, as you already mused.

The Java Card API for classic is clearly not designed for multi-threading, and for most smart cards true multi-threading would be a very high burden, especially regarding RAM usage. Furthermore, the half-duplex APDU interface of ISO/IEC 7816-4 would severely limit the usefulness of multi-threading. Currently you cannot do *much* more than interleaving APDU command/response pairs sequentially.

---

Note that there are now dual-core smart card processors. But don't be fooled by appearances; those cores essentially run *the same thread*. They are mainly used to add security to a platform: if one processor state is found to be different from the other then a fault detection is triggered and the platform can launch defense measures.

Comment: Thanks Mr Owlstead. Excuse me, In Card with more than one logical channel, is it possible to write two applet in a way that when we select each one on e logical channel, we make a dead-lock? I mean is it possible to occur deadlock in javacard? (with two different applet or even in a single applet). if so, how?

Comment: Within two different applets of two different modules you can only deadlock if you share services through the firewall. In principle you can create resource contention (and therefore deadlock) between two logical channels, but you would almost have to seek it out, and only one channel will be blocked - the other channel cannot submit an APDU until the one of the current APDU returns.